# Full calendar header title to match week

Tags: fullcalendar

I am utilizing `fullcalendar` and I configured the calendar to not include weekends:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        weekends: false,
```

However the `header` `title` attribute shows the dates ranging from Sunday to Saturday. Is there a way to change the title so that the date range also doesn't include weekends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this [github issue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2884). I just tested with the newest fullcalendar 2.9.1 and it works. You'll have to swap the function with the one in fullcalendar.js on line `8091`.

```
computeTitle: function () {

    var startDate, endDate;

    if (this.intervalUnit == 'month') {
        startDate = this.intervalStart;
        endDate = this.intervalEnd;
    }

    else {
        startDate = this.start;
        endDate = this.end;
    }

    return this.formatRange(
    { start: startDate, end: endDate },
        this.opt('titleFormat') || this.computeTitleFormat(),
        this.opt('titleRangeSeparator')
    );
}
```